Azure powershell script that updates the ADF trigger timing based on environment (DEV ,QA & PROD) CD
in my ADF we have multiple triggers we need to update the trigger time based on environment below is the code for 1 trigger "Dwh_Business_Days_MTD_Data_Load"
while seting the trigger time it throw error
##[error]Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.ScheduleTrigger
$adf_name = $env:Adf_Name
$resourcegroup_name = $env:ResourceGroup_Name

$blobContainerName = $env:blobContainerName
$StorageAccountName= $env:StorageAccountName

Write-Host "adf_name : $adf_name "
Write-Host "resourcegroup_name : $resourcegroup_name "
Write-Host "blobContainerName : $blobContainerName "
Write-Host "StorageAccountName: $StorageAccountName"

$triggerName = "Dwh_Business_Days_MTD_Data_Load"  
Write-Host "triggerName: $triggerName"
#"Dwh_Business_Days_MTD_Data_Load"  "Dwh_Salesforce_Belden_Data_Load"  

# Step 3: Get the trigger
$trigger = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -DataFactoryName $adf_name -Name $triggerName

Write-Host ($trigger.Properties | Format-List -Property * | Out-String)

Write-Host $trigger.Properties.AdditionalProperties.typeProperties.recurrence.frequency
 
# Set the frequency to "Day" and the time to "08:15:00" (8:15 AM)
#$trigger.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.frequency = "Day"
#$trigger.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.interval = 1
#$trigger.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.startTime = (Get-Date "08:15 AM")
#$trigger.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.hours= "[8]"
#$trigger.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.minutes= "[30]"

#Stop the trigger
Stop-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -DataFactoryName $adf_name -Name $triggerName -Force

# Update the trigger
Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -DataFactoryName $adf_name -Name $triggerName -Definition $trigger -Force


#Start the trigger
Star-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -DataFactoryName $adf_name -Name $triggerName -Force

Log of set time task
what i can try next?
